# What does it mean to say the keyword "private" is private at the class level?

Tags: java, class, private, comparable

A source I am reading says that the keyword `private` means a method or variable is private at the class level, not the object level.

Meaning in a chunk of code like this:

```
public class Weight2 implements Comparable<Weight2>
{
   private int myPounds, myOunces;

   public Weight2()
   {
      myPounds = myOunces = 0;
   }
   public Weight2(int x, int y)
   {
      myPounds = x;
      myOunces = y; 
   }

   public int compareTo(Weight2 w)
   {
      if(myPounds<w.myPounds)
         return -1;
      if(myPounds>w.myPounds)
         return 1;
      if(myOunces<w.myOunces)
         return -1;
      if(myOunces>w.myOunces)
         return 1;
      return 0;
   }
}
```

A Weight2 object can access the private fields of a different weight2 object without an accessor method... but rather by just saying `w.myPounds`.

CLARIFICATION:

I want to know from where objects can access *a different object's* private data. Is it only from within the class? Or could this be done from a driver program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private)

Comment: My question is not about the difference between the tags. It's about what `private` entails within a class... A more technical detail not answered in the thread you cite.

Comment: "What exactly does it mean to say that privacy is given at the class level, and not the object level?"  It means that "...objects of the same type [can] access each other's private fields without accessor methods."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A source I am reading says that the keyword private means a method or
>   variable is private at the class level, not the object level.

I don't know your source. It is not wrong but it is not clear either.

You could refer to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) that bring this information about the **private** modifier :

> **Chapter 6. Names**
>
> **6.6.1. Determining Accessibility**
>
> ... the member or constructor is declared private, and access is
>   permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level
>   class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or
>   constructor.

About :

> So what I mean to ask is, can objects of the same type access each
>   other's private fields without accessor methods?

Indeed.

And it is rather consistent with the specification.
It doesn't restrict the access to `private` members to only the current instance.
So, you may consider that this limitation doesn't exist and so you can invoke `private` method for current instance or any variable referencing the current class.
And it is of course true in static as in instance contexts.

---

As a side note, you should also take into consideration the level access: class and instance.
The `private static` modifiers means a method or variable is private at the class level. So, you don't need any instance to refer it.
While the `private` modifier (without the `static` modifier) means a method or variable is private at the instance level.
So you need an instance to refer it.

---

Comment: Thank you... sorry for the lack of clarification in my question... I did mean to say `w.myPounds`.

Comment: You have a good point - upvoting excellent content is absolutely fair! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> So what I mean to ask is, can objects of the same type access each
>   other's private fields without accessor methods?

Yes, they can.

Access modifiers in Java are about Class'es, not about instances.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your question is exactly. However I will give you a basic summary of what i think you want.

If a variable or a method is private then it can only be accessed or used within the class in which it exists.

If a variable or a method is public then it can be accessed by other classes.

Have a look at this website it may assist you it certainly helped me.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html